# htmlspecialchars() on array of values fetch

Tags: php, arrays, security, xss, htmlspecialchars

Lets say I fetch data with PDO

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $result;
```

How should I use htmlspecialchars() before displaying the results using echo on the view page? Is is ok to escape the array of results right after fetchall() or I should escape all results one by one in the view page?

If I were to use htmlspecialchars() right after fetch, would the following work?

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $results=  implode(',', $results);
    $results= htmlspecialchars($results);
    $results= explode(',', $results);
    return $results;
```

Comment: Do it on the view page

Comment: Well this is part of presentation, so it should be handled in your View of your Model, View, Controller application framework. You're using a MVC framework right? If not, why work so hard, get Symfony and let the framework take care of these details. In Symfony there are a myriad number of ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah well Im creating my own CMS and I want to learn so I'm doing the MVC on my own but once I understand the concept perfectly, I'll absolutely use a framework.

Comment: In the method you showed, you fetch data with PDO. I recommend not doing anything else in that method. Regardless of whether you're doing MVC or some other pattern, I think it's best to follow the single responsibility principle. What if you later realize you want to do something else (filter, sort, transform, etc. ) with the data from that method before outputting it? If it's already been `htmlspecialchars`ed, it could easily interfere with that. Look at the major frameworks; they all use some sort of template system where the output is escaped at the time it is output.

Comment: thanks for the advice ill do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding whether your solution in the question actually works (it does not as Marc B pointed out), technically it doesn't matter *where* you encode values as long as they are encoded before being written into the page. So it's pretty much your design decision.

Let me note though that htmlspecialchars() is not the holy grail against XSS. It only protects you when output is written in an HTML context, but not when it's written into Javascript for example.

Consider this:

```
...your html content...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar = <?= myVar ?>;
</script>
...
```

In this case, calling htmlspecialchars() on myVar is not enough if it may contain user input. In the example above, you don't actually need any special character to exploit XSS. The same applies to things like `<div onclick="myFun('something', <?=myVar?>)">` -- as it's still a Javascript context, you need a different encoding.

A full tutorial on XSS does not fit (and I believe does not belong) in an answer here, just wanted to raise attention to the fact that HTML encoding is not always enough at all.

Having said that, applying htmlspecialchars() right after reading data from a database is I think wrong, because at that point you probably don't care about where data will be used (what context it will be written into). It may also be a separation of concerns thing in your code.

So I would spare encoding data until it actually gets written into the page, because then you know what encoding to use.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchAll` returns an array of arrays. You're imploding only the OUTER array (rows), which means you're trying to convert the inner arrays (fields/values) into strings, and you'll get the literal string `Array,Array,Array,etc...`.

So, no, it wouldn't work.

Comment: would using array_walk do the job then?

Comment: Why don't you try it? We're happy to help. We're not here to execute/debug your code for you.  Especially when you're just poking around in the dark.

Comment: Because I dont understand htmlspecialchars() 100% and I wanted to make sure it was secure and I have no way of knowing if it is or not, Im still new to PHP and I thought someone would point me in the right direction. I didnt say I wanted anyone to give me the code, I just asked if it could be done with array_walk, thats it.......

Comment: secure for what? security isn't something you can just sprinkle onto code like salt on food and it's magically "better".

Comment: duh... What makes u think I only use htmlspecialchars to make my site more secure?

Comment: I've learned not to "think". You have no idea what some people think will make their site secure.

Comment: well so far ive used hash_password(), I use PDO with binding params. Now I will use htmspecialchars(). Any other thing I can do to make it more secure?

Comment: @coder_1432, there is no `one best set of security techniques`. They are a compromise between cost, and threats that you must guard against, for a _given set of circumstances_. Here we mention some techniques that are reliable given that your description of the circumstances is fairly complete. Please note - I use the techniques mentioned in your list. imo, It is really about thinking in a slightly paranoid manner when programming for the web. :)

Comment: @coder_1432: so that helps with the database. htmlspecialchars has nothing to do with sql. you can't just "does using X make me secure". you have to ask "does doing X for purpose/use Y make me secure", and then explain what your threat environment is too.